# Adding a generic class to a list that takes generic type

Tags: java, list, generics

I have a Field as below,

```
public class Field<T> {
    private T eventField;
    /**
     * @return the eventField
     */
    public T getEventField() {
        return eventField;
    }
    /**
     * @param eventField the eventField to set
     */
    public void setEventField(T eventField) {
        this.eventField = eventField;
    }
}
```

Now i have declared a List which takes in 'Field' of generic type 'Object'. But when i create Field of type string and try to add to the List, it fails.
Please help me understand this from the underlying reason.

```
List<Field<Object>> l = new ArrayList<Field<Object>>();
Field<String> f = new Field<String>();
f.setEventField("Hi");

l.add(f);
```

Comment: Nope. `Field<Object>` is **not** a supertype of `Field<String>`.

Comment: `Field<?>` is a supertype of both `Field<Object>` and `Field<String>`

Answer (score 3):

You declare a List of `Field<Object>` :

```
    List<Field<Object>> l = new ArrayList<Field<Object>>();
```

So you cannot add in a `Field<String>`.

You could declare

```
List<Field<? extends Object>> l = new ArrayList<Field<? extends Object>>();
```

or the shorthand version :

```
List<Field<?>> l = new ArrayList<Field<?>>();
```

and it will be valid :

```
 Field<String> f = new Field<String>();
 f.setEventField("Hi");
 l.add(f);
```